# Firebase Dynamics Links java client connection

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Recently I had some task to integrate open source url short service.
I had choose firebase  dynamic links by google  , i did not managed to find some decent how to tutorial or quick start.
I have managed to execute the service and get the answer.
I would like to get some improvement suggestions for client initialization.

gradle dependency used

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-firebasedynamiclinks:v1-rev860-1.25.0'
```

code

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.Builder builder = new FirebaseDynamicLinks.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null);
        FirebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer firebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer = new FirebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer(
                "***WEB_API_KEY***");
        builder.setApplicationName("***Fire_Bass_Dummy_App***");
        builder.setFirebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer(firebaseDynamicLinksRequestInitializer);
        FirebaseDynamicLinks firebasedynamiclinks = builder.build();
        CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest createShortLinkRequest = new CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest();
        createShortLinkRequest.setLongDynamicLink("***Dynamic_Links_domain***?link=***long_link***");
        Suffix suffix = new Suffix();
        suffix.setOption("SHORT");
        createShortLinkRequest.setSuffix(suffix);
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.ShortLinks.Create request = firebasedynamiclinks.shortLinks().create(createShortLinkRequest);
        CreateShortDynamicLinkResponse createShortDynamicLinkResponse = request.execute();
```